# apply filter to ngRepeat from different controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I apply a filter to `ngRepeat` from a different controller?

From the `Filters` controller how do I `applyFilter()`:

```
<div ng-controller="Filters">
    <span ng-click="applyFilter()"></span>
</div>
```

... To `items` in the `Results` controller

```
<div ng-controller="Results">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.thing}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `applyFilter` supposed to do?

Comment: @lucuma apply a filter.

Comment: You want to filter the list using standard angular filters?

Comment: @lucuma yea I think? what's the best way to handle this?

Comment: I added an example demo with a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either a parent controller or a service.  The first example below uses a parent controller to define the items and filter value to share it with the two child controllers.  The second example demonstrates the use of a service that is injected to both controllers and doesn't require a parent controller.

**Parent Controller example:**  I would have one parent controller for both and define the data and filter value in that controller. This will allow each child controller to easily process and manipulate the filter:

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yrtsX5SQsRiNSho6o9x8?p=preview

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Hello {{name}}!

  <div ng-controller="Filters">
    <span ng-click="applyFilter()">Apply Filter</span>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="Results">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items |  filter:filterFunc ">
    {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Controllers:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  $scope.filterVal = 0;

});

app.controller('Filters', function($scope) {
    $scope.applyFilter = function() {
           $scope.$parent.filterVal = 5;  
           $scope.$apply();
    }
});

app.controller('Results', function($scope) {
 $scope.filterFunc= function(item) {
    console.log(item);
     if (item>$scope.filterVal)
      return item;
    }

});
```

**Services Example.**  Here is an updated example with a service which contains the filter value and the items.  http://plnkr.co/edit/wZFKBMRv0SeEsXNqARe2?p=preview

```
app.controller('Filters', function($scope, Utils) {
    $scope.applyFilter = function() {
          Utils.setFilter(4);
    }
});



app.controller('Results', function($scope, Utils) {
  $scope.items = Utils.getItems();
 $scope.filterFunc= function(item) {
    console.log(item);
     if (item>Utils.getFilter())
      return item;
    }

});

angular.module('ServicesUtils', []).
   factory('Utils', [ function () {

      var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
      var filter = 0;

      var service = {
        getFilter:function() {
          return filter;
        },
        getItems:function() {
         return items;
        },
        setFilter:function(n) {
          filter = n;
        }
      };

     return service;

    }]);
```

Comment: do you "have to" use a parent controller? are there any other techniques you could reference?

Comment: You will probably need to store the items and filter info in a service if you don't want to use a parent controller

Comment: I see. So the click event would update the filter value in the service shared by both controllers.

Comment: Yes, that would work as well. You are sharing the item information one way or another either through the parent controller or via a service but the idea is the same.

Comment: If applying filters is the only job of the parent controller, which method makes more sence?

Comment: Services are generally cleaner and easier to test, but it depends on the overall architecture of your app.  How are you defining items, where are you getting them, where else are you using them, etc?